# insert and extract hour an minute from oracle

Tags: java, sql

I work with oracle

I want to insert data which contains hour and minute

I have this column : **DATE_ARCH**

the type of this column is **date**

I have this java code which should insert date in this column

```
 transfers.setDateArch(new java.sql.Date(
                        System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

but when I try to extract hour and minute from **DATE_ARCH**

using this sql code :

```
select to_char(transfers.DATE_ARCH , 'HH:MM') from transfers where id_transfer='TR-300'
```

I have all time this value :

**12:05**

**Updated** :

I try with this code :

```
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());

                transfers.setDateArch(t);
```

I try to extract hour and minute using this code :

```
select to_char(transfers.DATE_ARCH , 'HH24:MI') from transfers where id_transfer='TR-258'
```

but I have in all case this value :

**00:00**

as I already said   the type of **DATE_ARCH**  is **date**

When I try in sql with :

```
  UPDATE transfers SET DATE_ARCH = SYSDATE
```

I have the correct value  using

```
 select to_char(transfers.DATE_ARCH , 'HH24:MI') from transfers where id_transfer='TR-258'
```

now I want to know how can I insert date with hour and minute using java code

Comment: What do you want to retrieve?  You are converting the value to a character with only the hour and minute, so it shouldn't surprise you that you are only getting the hour and minute.

Comment: the problem that I have in all time  12:05 , I think that 12:05 is a default value,  because I try to save in different time   but I have in all case   12:05

Comment: As documented in the JavaDocs: a `java.sql.Date` has not time (it's set to `0`). You need to use `java.sql.Timestamp`. And `MM` returns the month, not the minutes (see the Oracle manual).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  I do not know enough about the java interface to Oracle to know the right solution.  But, your solution is inserting the date with no time.  The expression:

```
to_char(transfers.DATE_ARCH , 'HH:MM')
```

is returning "12" because that is midnight and "05" because it is May.  The correct expression for minutes is:

```
to_char(transfers.DATE_ARCH , 'HH:MI')
```

and for a 24-hour clock:

```
to_char(transfers.DATE_ARCH , 'HH24:MI')
```

I do not, alas, know how to fix the java code.  But perhaps there is a `DateTime` method that you can use.