# Oracle Database: getting hours as int value from passed date and time parameter

Tags: oracle

i am passing current machine date and time as named hibernate query parameter. Like `SELECT * FROM VISITS WHERE VISIT_TIME > :dateTime`
How can i get hours from *dateTime* parameter and convert it to integer value?

Comment: `extract(hour from :datetime)`

Comment: `extract(hour from ..)` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions059.htm#SQLRF00639

Comment: if you search _oracle extract hour from datetime_ you'll find [insert and extract hour an minute from oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575110/insert-and-extract-hour-an-minute-from-oracle). A simple to_char(datecolumn,'hh24') will to the job, but also what Gordon and a_horse_with_no_name already mentioned works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle knows two ways to extract the hour. One is `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM xx)` where xx must be a timestamp unfortunately:

```
select * from visits where visit_time > extract(hour from cast(:datetime as timestamp)
```

The other is `TO_CHAR(xx, 'HH24')` which gives you a string:

```
select * from visits where visit_time > to_number(to_char(:datetime, 'hh24'))
```